# how to preserve modifications to common files after deleting feature branch without merge?

Tags: git, git-branch

Suppose I have a feature branch in which I make changes to the `.gitignore` common file in addition to the core modifications to the branch. And suppose I decide to delete the feature branch after making commits but forego merging with the master branch. How can I preserve the changes I made to the `.gitignore` file without loosing them when I delete the feature branch?

Edit: what if I want to preserve changes to multiple common files?

Comment: Honestly I might just save the `.gitignore` file somewhere, then checkout `master` and paste the contents of that saved file.

Comment: if the changes are in a separate commit you could cherry-pick it to master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Tim Biegeleisen noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546044/how-to-preserve-modifications-to-common-files-after-deleting-feature-branch-with#comment119389517_67546044), you don't *have* to do this in Git.  For a single file like this, it's probably just as easy, or even easier, to just bypass Git entirely in terms of slinging the updated file around:

```
cp .gitignore /tmp/save    # the .gitignore update was good, but
git checkout master
git branch -D feature      # the feature idea turned out to be bad
mv /tmp/save .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit
```

(and then write up a good commit message).

As [Jasen noted in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546044/how-to-preserve-modifications-to-common-files-after-deleting-feature-branch-with#comment119389699_67546044), if you committed this `.gitignore` update by itself, you can easily cherry-pick the commit from the feature branch.  You can do this before *or after* deleting the feature branch, but it will be far easier to *find* the commit if you do it *before* deleting the feature branch.  For instance:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick feature~3   # the good idea was 3 commits back
git branch -D feature
```

If the commit message could use some tweaking, add `--edit` to your `git cherry-pick` command.

Last—and this is more useful if there are multiple files to update since then the `/tmp/save` method is insufficient—you can use `git restore` (found only in Git 2.23 or later) to copy specific files, in their committed form, from some other commit.  So if the final commit in the feature branch has a nice improvement to the `.gitignore` file, but you don't want anything else from it:

```
git checkout master
git restore --source=feature --staged --worktree -- .gitignore
git branch -D feature
git commit
```

The `--staged --worktree` here causes the new-and-improved file to be staged-for-commit already, so that no separate `git add` is required.

If you don't have `git restore`, `git checkout` has a mode where it does exactly the same as the above:

```
git checkout master
git checkout feature -- .gitignore
git branch -D feature
git commit
```

This `git checkout specifier -- paths` command has exactly the same effect as `git restore --source=specifier --staged --worktree -- paths`.  Note that this form of `git checkout`, with the `-- paths` part, means *go ahead and destroy any unsaved work without asking* (as does `git restore` in general).

#### What if you've already deleted the feature branch?

To answer the title question, *all of the Git methods above still work* as long as you can find the *correct commit hash ID*.  This hash ID will be found in the reflog for `HEAD`.  It would be easier to find in the reflog for the branch name (`feature`, in this case), but unfortunately, that reflog gets deleted when the branch name is deleted.

So, run `git reflog`—its default is to show the `HEAD` reflog—and find a suitable commit hash ID.  Then use the mouse to cut-and-paste the hash ID as the `--source` for `git restore`, for instance.